# Protractor DataProvider. 1st Data constantly skipped when test is run

Tags: javascript, testing, jasmine, protractor, automated-tests

The 1st  bit of data is constantly skipped. I don't know why

[I explain in more  detail in this video](https://www.dropbox.com/s/qotcmvb1deka0ri/problem.mp4?dl=0)

Question:

1 what did I do wrong?

2. How do I fix it?

**IT case spec name:  PageObjectLocator2.js**

```
describe('protractor page Object  training',function(){
    var obj= require("./PageObjectDemo.js");
    var using= require ('jasmine-data-provider');
    var d= require("./data1.js");


    beforeEach(function() {
        obj.geturl();//the url on your test page is a method

      });

    //data = this the actual data items 
    //description =  This are names you given each set of data

    using(d.DataDriver, function (data, description){
    //test scenarios can only be carried out in this area. Place your IT block here!!!

        it('Perform Simple Calculation ',function(){
            // write your code here!!!

                obj.firstnumber.sendKeys(data.firstinput);//page of object properties
                obj.secondnumber.sendKeys(data.secondinput);//page object properties

                obj.gobutton.click();

                //Jasmine Attribute Syntax toBe. Jasmine takes care of the promise 'resolve'internally

                expect(obj.result.getText()).toBe(data.result);     
                //this confirm printout in console.

           obj.result.getText().then(function(text){
                console.log(text) 
             }) //end of console log message           


            })//end of it block


    });//end of data testing block 



    afterEach(function () {
       console.log("If you can see this, test is completed. Well Done!!");
    });
```

**2.Data spec name : Data1.js**

This is the data provider section.   It looks ok and I it didn't have any error messages.  so it makes no sense that I am having this issue.

```
  module.exports=
    {

    DataDriver:
    {

        FirstData: 
        {
            firstinput:"3",
            secondinput:"5",
            result: "8"
        },

        SecondData:
        {
            firstinput:"3",
            secondinput:"6",
            result: "9"
        },

        ThirdData:
        {
            firstinput:"5",
            secondinput:"5",
            result: "10"
        }

           }
                }
```

**3. print out from terminal**

Finally The message from the console after running `npm run protractor` at local project level.  As you can see **The 1st dataprovider item has been skipped for some reason.**

```
> LocatorTraining@ protractor /Users/jacquelinegeorge/Documents/JSworkspace/LocatorTraining
> protractor configurations.js


[21:04:46] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver
[21:04:46] I/hosted - Using the selenium server at http://localhost:4444/wd/hub
Started
If you can see this, test is completed. Well Done!!
F9
If you can see this, test is completed. Well Done!!
.10
If you can see this, test is completed. Well Done!!
.


Failures:
1) protractor page Object  training Perform Simple Calculation 
  Message:
    WebDriverError: unknown error: failed to change window state to maximized, current state is normal
      (Session info: chrome=70.0.3538.77)
      (Driver info: chromedriver=2.43.600229 (3fae4d0cda5334b4f533bede5a4787f7b832d052),platform=Mac OS X 10.13.6 x86_64)
  Stack:
    WebDriverError: unknown error: failed to change window state to maximized, current state is normal
      (Session info: chrome=70.0.3538.77)
      (Driver info: chromedriver=2.43.600229 (3fae4d0cda5334b4f533bede5a4787f7b832d052),platform=Mac OS X 10.13.6 x86_64)
        at Object.checkLegacyResponse (/Users/jacquelinegeorge/Documents/JSworkspace/LocatorTraining/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/error.js:546:15)
        at parseHttpResponse (/Users/jacquelinegeorge/Documents/JSworkspace/LocatorTraining/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/http.js:509:13)
        at doSend.then.response (/Users/jacquelinegeorge/Documents/JSworkspace/LocatorTraining/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/http.js:441:30)
        at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:103:7)
    From: Task: WebDriver.manage().window().maximize()
        at thenableWebDriverProxy.schedule (/Users/jacquelinegeorge/Documents/JSworkspace/LocatorTraining/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver.js:807:17)
        at Window.maximize (/Users/jacquelinegeorge/Documents/JSworkspace/LocatorTraining/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver.js:1686:25)
        at onPrepare (/Users/jacquelinegeorge/Documents/JSworkspace/LocatorTraining/configurations.js:10:37)
        at q_1.Promise (/Users/jacquelinegeorge/Documents/JSworkspace/LocatorTraining/node_modules/protractor/built/util.js:46:49)
        at Function.promise (/Users/jacquelinegeorge/Documents/JSworkspace/LocatorTraining/node_modules/q/q.js:682:9)
        at Object.runFilenameOrFn_ (/Users/jacquelinegeorge/Documents/JSworkspace/LocatorTraining/node_modules/protractor/built/util.js:38:16)
        at plugins_.onPrepare.then (/Users/jacquelinegeorge/Documents/JSworkspace/LocatorTraining/node_modules/protractor/built/runner.js:98:27)
        at _fulfilled (/Users/jacquelinegeorge/Documents/JSworkspace/LocatorTraining/node_modules/q/q.js:834:54)
        at self.promiseDispatch.done (/Users/jacquelinegeorge/Documents/JSworkspace/LocatorTraining/node_modules/q/q.js:863:30)
        at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/Users/jacquelinegeorge/Documents/JSworkspace/LocatorTraining/node_modules/q/q.js:796:13)
  Message:
    Failed: Error while waiting for Protractor to sync with the page: "both angularJS testability and angular testability are undefined.  This could be either because this is a non-angular page or because your test involves client-side navigation, which can interfere with Protractor's bootstrapping.  See http://git.io/v4gXM for details"
  Stack:
    Error: Error while waiting for Protractor to sync with the page: "both angularJS testability and angular testability are undefined.  This could be either because this is a non-angular page or because your test involves client-side navigation, which can interfere with Protractor's bootstrapping.  See http://git.io/v4gXM for details"
        at runWaitForAngularScript.then (/Users/jacquelinegeorge/Documents/JSworkspace/LocatorTraining/node_modules/protractor/built/browser.js:463:23)
        at ManagedPromise.invokeCallback_ (/Users/jacquelinegeorge/Documents/JSworkspace/LocatorTraining/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:1376:14)
        at TaskQueue.execute_ (/Users/jacquelinegeorge/Documents/JSworkspace/LocatorTraining/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:3084:14)
        at TaskQueue.executeNext_ (/Users/jacquelinegeorge/Documents/JSworkspace/LocatorTraining/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:3067:27)
        at asyncRun (/Users/jacquelinegeorge/Documents/JSworkspace/LocatorTraining/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:2927:27)
        at /Users/jacquelinegeorge/Documents/JSworkspace/LocatorTraining/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:668:7
        at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:103:7)Error
        at ElementArrayFinder.applyAction_ (/Users/jacquelinegeorge/Documents/JSworkspace/LocatorTraining/node_modules/protractor/built/element.js:459:27)
        at ElementArrayFinder.(anonymous function) [as sendKeys] (/Users/jacquelinegeorge/Documents/JSworkspace/LocatorTraining/node_modules/protractor/built/element.js:91:29)
        at ElementFinder.(anonymous function) [as sendKeys] (/Users/jacquelinegeorge/Documents/JSworkspace/LocatorTraining/node_modules/protractor/built/element.js:831:22)
        at UserContext.<anonymous> (/Users/jacquelinegeorge/Documents/JSworkspace/LocatorTraining/PageObjectLocator2.js:21:21)
        at /Users/jacquelinegeorge/Documents/JSworkspace/LocatorTraining/node_modules/jasminewd2/index.js:112:25
        at new ManagedPromise (/Users/jacquelinegeorge/Documents/JSworkspace/LocatorTraining/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:1077:7)
        at ControlFlow.promise (/Users/jacquelinegeorge/Documents/JSworkspace/LocatorTraining/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:2505:12)
        at schedulerExecute (/Users/jacquelinegeorge/Documents/JSworkspace/LocatorTraining/node_modules/jasminewd2/index.js:95:18)
        at TaskQueue.execute_ (/Users/jacquelinegeorge/Documents/JSworkspace/LocatorTraining/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:3084:14)
        at TaskQueue.executeNext_ (/Users/jacquelinegeorge/Documents/JSworkspace/LocatorTraining/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:3067:27)
    From: Task: Run it("Perform Simple Calculation ") in control flow
        at UserContext.<anonymous> (/Users/jacquelinegeorge/Documents/JSworkspace/LocatorTraining/node_modules/jasminewd2/index.js:94:19)
        at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
        at process.emit (events.js:188:7)
    From asynchronous test: 
    Error
        at /Users/jacquelinegeorge/Documents/JSworkspace/LocatorTraining/PageObjectLocator2.js:18:3
        at /Users/jacquelinegeorge/Documents/JSworkspace/LocatorTraining/node_modules/jasmine-data-provider/src/index.js:37:22
        at Array.forEach (native)
        at /Users/jacquelinegeorge/Documents/JSworkspace/LocatorTraining/node_modules/jasmine-data-provider/src/index.js:30:24
        at Suite.<anonymous> (/Users/jacquelinegeorge/Documents/JSworkspace/LocatorTraining/PageObjectLocator2.js:15:2)
        at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/jacquelinegeorge/Documents/JSworkspace/LocatorTraining/PageObjectLocator2.js:1:63)


3 specs, 1 failure
Finished in 6.394 seconds


[21:04:54] I/launcher - 0 instance(s) of WebDriver still running
[21:04:54] I/launcher - chrome #01 failed 1 test(s)
[21:04:54] I/launcher - overall: 1 failed spec(s)
[21:04:54] E/launcher - Process exited with error code 1


npm ERR! Darwin 17.7.0
npm ERR! argv "/Users/jacquelinegeorge/.nvm/versions/node/v7.2.0/bin/node" "/Users/jacquelinegeorge/.nvm/versions/node/v7.2.0/bin/npm" "run" "protractor"
npm ERR! node v7.2.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.9
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! LocatorTraining@ protractor: `protractor configurations.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the LocatorTraining@ protractor script 'protractor configurations.js'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the LocatorTraining package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     protractor configurations.js
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs LocatorTraining
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls LocatorTraining
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.


npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /Users/jacquelinegeorge/Documents/JSworkspace/LocatorTraining/npm-debug.log
Jacquelines-MacBook-Air:Locator
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok,

I found the root cause of this issue.  It seems to **an issue with google Chrome browser**  and NOT my actual test.  If I run this test on FF its works fine.   So as far as I am concerned the this issue concerning the test is resolved - because there is no issue with my test.

I will open an issue concerning an actual issue with my Chrome and why its not running test properly.